# Which Google Play API is 'Advertising ID' in?

Tags: android, google-play-services, ads

I'm integrating an ad SDK, and their instructions say to add all of Google Play services. The only thing it says they use it for, however, is the advertising ID.

I want to include just that specific part of Google Play Services, but I'm not sure which one it's in.

Here's the docs for it: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/id.html

I would assume its in... `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0`, however when I look there [in the docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/package-summary), the class headings don't make any mention of the identifier (or any of the many other `ads` functions/classes in the sidebar... which leads me to believe `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads` might not include what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use the Advertising ID you only need to include:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.4.0
```

You can see in which library is included directly in Android Studio:

[image]

Also, you can find the documentation of the Advertising ID in the [ads.identifier](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/package-summary) section.

Comment: Very interesting... can I see where that's written in the docs? Not that I don't believe you, just that I was trying to figure it out myself and I couldn't find `base` defined in the docs where it showed all it's functions.

Comment: As a follow up question, does calling `gms:play-services-ads` also call `base`, or are they completely exclusive to each other?

Comment: Unfortunately i never found this info written in the documentation, but you can find out directly in Android Studio, as you can see in the updated answer. Either `play-services-ads` and `play-services-base` have `play-services-basement` as dependency, so you can directly use `play-services-basement`

Comment: I'm not sure which version it changed in, but as of the current play-services 15.0.1 you have to use `play-services-ads-identifier` instead of `play-services-basement` - basement no longer contains the necessary class.

Answer (score 0):

The advertising id is the following undocumented package:

com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.0